# on click of the button smoothly show remaining overflowed hidden text in div

Tags: jquery, slide

Let's say I have a div with `max-height` of 100px and text in it the overflows

```
div {position:absolute;top:0;left:0;background:red;max- height:100px;width:100px; display:flex;flex-wrap:wrap;position:relative}
```

And I have a button at the bottom of it:

```
button {position:absolute;bottom:0;width:100%;height:30px;background:blue;}
```

And what I try to do with jquery is: on click of the button to smoothly slide it down and show all the remaining hidden text in the div.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean something like this? https://jsfiddle.net/s6ypy4w1/

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('div').css('height', 'auto');
  var thisHeight = $('div').height();
  $('div').css('height', 100);
  $("button").on('click', function() {
    $('div').animate({
      'height': thisHeight
    })
  });
});
```

The jQuery sets the height to auto breifly to store the 'auto' height then restores it to the initial height you'd like it to be. Then it animates to that stored height on button click. Hope this helps!

Comment: yes, but i need to toggle it - so if the div is shown and I ckick th ebutton it will be hidden again

Answer (score 0):

You can use several approaches here:

1. CSS only: hard to do it, because we do not know the final max-height
   value. Therefor we would have to animate to some fixed value (for example to 300px or 10em). Also, backward animation would be hard to implement, than if you use checkboxes as we have in example below, than you need to assign individual IDs (could be extended by script though).
2. jQuery + CSS: if we want to make this responsive, than we need to calculate the height of the expanded element. In the example below we count the text lines and multiply with line-height.
3. For non-responsive website, or if you have always fixed width, just use [aender's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3053568/aender) solution he posted here.

**CSS ONLY** ([fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/vv5efts3/1/))

```css
.overflow-box {
    line-height: 1.5em;
 overflow: hidden;
 margin: 20px 0;
 position: relative;
 border: 1px solid #ccc;
}

.overflow-box input {
    display: none;
}

.overflow-box label {
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
 z-index: 100;
    top: 4.5em;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    background: none #fff;
}

.overflow-content {
    max-height: 6em;
    overflow: hidden;
 transition: max-height 0s;
}

.overflow-box input:checked + label {
 top: auto;
 bottom: 0;
}

.overflow-box input:checked + label + .overflow-content {
    max-height: 20em;
 margin-bottom: 1.5em;
 transition: .5s ease-in-out;
}
```

```html
<div class="overflow-box">
    <input id="o1" type="checkbox" />
    <label for="o1" class="overflow-button">
        Click me
    </label>
    <div class="overflow-content">
        This is responsive: Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor
        in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur.
    </div>
</div>

<div class="overflow-box">
    <input id="o2" type="checkbox" />
    <label for="o2" class="overflow-button">
        Click me
    </label>
    <div class="overflow-content">
        Short content, one line.
    </div>
</div>

<div class="overflow-box">
    <input id="o3" type="checkbox" />
    <label for="o3" class="overflow-button">
        Click me
    </label>
    <div class="overflow-content">
        4 lines content.
        <br> 4 lines content.
        <br> 4 lines content.
        <br> 4 lines content.
    </div>
</div>
```

**jQuery + CSS** ([fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/s834dc14/2/))

```js
var maxLines = 3;
var lineHeight = 1.5; /* em */
var boxes = $('.overflow-box');
function checkBox(box, content, toggle, text) {
 var lines = text[0].getClientRects().length;
 console.log('lines: ' + lines);
 if( lines>maxLines ) {
  box.removeClass('overflow-short');
  if( box.hasClass('overflow-expanded')) {
   content.css({'max-height': (lines*lineHeight)+'em'});
  } else {
   content.css({'max-height': (maxLines*lineHeight)+'em'});
  };
 } else {
  box.addClass('overflow-short');
 };
};
boxes.each(function(i){
 var thisBox = $(this);
 var thisContent = thisBox.find('.overflow-content');
 thisContent.wrapInner('<div class="overflow-content-inner"></div>');
 var thisToggle = thisBox.find('.overflow-toggle');
 var thisText = thisBox.find('.overflow-content-inner');
 checkBox(thisBox, thisContent, thisToggle, thisText);
 thisToggle.on('click', function(e) {
  thisBox.toggleClass('overflow-expanded');
  checkBox(thisBox, thisContent, thisToggle, thisText);
 });
 $(window).on('resize', function(e) {
  checkBox(thisBox, thisContent, thisToggle, thisText);
 });
});
```

```css
.overflow-box {
 line-height: 1.5em;
 margin: 20px 0;
 border: 1px solid #ccc;
}
.overflow-content {
 overflow: hidden;
 transition: .5s ease-in-out;
}
.overflow-content-inner {
 display: inline;
}
.overflow-toggle {
 width: 100%;
 text-align: center;
    background: none #fff;
 cursor: pointer;
}
.overflow-short .overflow-toggle {
 display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="overflow-box">
    <div class="overflow-content">
        This is responsive: Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor
        in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur.
    </div>
 <div class="overflow-toggle">
  Click me
 </div>
</div>

<div class="overflow-box">
    <div class="overflow-content">
        Short content, one line.
    </div>
 <div class="overflow-toggle">
  Click me
 </div>
</div>

<div class="overflow-box">
    <div class="overflow-content">
        4 lines content.
        <br> 4 lines content.
        <br> 4 lines content.
        <br> 4 lines content.
    </div>
 <div class="overflow-toggle">
  Click me
 </div>
</div>
```